# spring-security java config: How to configure Multiple AuthenticationManager instances

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot

I use:

- spring boot: 1.1.7
- spring-security: 4.0.0.M2
- spring-fmk: 4.1.1.RELEASE

Everything is configured with Java Config (including spring-security)

I'm working on a web server project where Authentication: Basic base64Gibberish header are used to authenticate users.

The problem is that depending on the URI the `AuthenticationManager` is different (because I need 2 different `UserDetailsService`.

- /URI1/** => authManager1
- /URI2/** => authManager2

I've tried multiple extensions of `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` with

```
@Override
@Bean( name = "authManager1" )
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
```

```java
@Override
@Bean( name = "authManager2" )
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
```

to no avail

I always get:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' 
defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: 
Factory method [public javax.servlet.Filter org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain() throws java.lang.Exception] 
threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Expecting to only find a single bean for type interface org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager, 
but found [authManager1, authManager2]
```

Since I have multiple security filter chains how can I "tell" spring-security to inject different AuthenticationManager in different security filter chains ?

Thanks in advance
P.

Comment: I have the same prob. How you have created separate AuthManagers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can have multiple http configuration elements, each with its own `AuthenticationManager`. It could look like that :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager1() {
        // defines first AuthenticationManager
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager2() {
        // defines second AuthenticationManager
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class Uri1ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(authenticationManager1)
        private authManager1;

        @Override
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
            return authManager1;
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/URI1/**")
                ...
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class Uri2ApiConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier(authenticationManager2)
        private authManager2;

        @Override
        protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
            return authManager2;
        }

        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .antMatcher("/URI2/**")
                ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer due to below reasons:

- You cannot have the private method in the class annotated with Configuration because Bean-method in Configuration must be overridable.
- authenticationManager1 is not accessible in the nested class and there is no point of referencing it here => Qualifier(authenticationManager1).