# How to convert spring security xml configuration to java configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to convert the below xml to java configuration, but confused with `alias` argument in the sec:authentication-manager tag. I have worked on the partial part of java configuration and will appreciate if someone can help me with rest of configuration.

### Xml Configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"

       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder"/>

    <sec:authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <sec:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder"/>
        </sec:authentication-provider>
    </sec:authentication-manager>

    <sec:authentication-manager id="clientAuthenticationManager" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <sec:authentication-provider user-service-ref="client-details-user-service"/>
    </sec:authentication-manager>


    <bean id="client-details-user-service" class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="client-details-service" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

### Converted partial

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private ClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private Validator validator;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.authenticationManager();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }


       @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return new UserServiceImpl(userRepository, validator, passwordEncoder);
        } 



}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `alias` tag is for identify this specific authentication-manager. If you doesn't need this in the `java-config`, you can try the following:

```
@Autowired
private StandardPasswordEncoder standardPasswordEncoder;

@Override
public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(principalService).passwordEncoder(standardPasswordEncoder);
    auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
   auth.userDetailsService(principalService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
   auth.authenticationProvider(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider());
}

@Bean
public PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider(){
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
    preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(preAuthenticationUserDetailService);
    return preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want multiply authentication manager check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26308661/1809221

Comment: i just to convert line to line in javaconfiguration, can you help me how to have two authentication manager in security config java file?

Answer (score 0):

Java config can do the same as namespace configuration in XML.

I would advice you to follow the following rules in you `@Configuration` class:

- all that is declared with `<bean ...>` in xml should be a `@Bean` in java config
- all beans that are defined elsewhere and used in this xml should be @Autowired

As you have 2 different authentication managers in xml, you should create them explicitely in Java config, because the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26305942) refered by @ManuZi shows that instantiation of springSecurityFilterChain fails if you try to configure 2 different `AuthenticationManager` through a basic java configuration, and you should better use explicit injection with `@Qualifier` annotations.